# unir dos querys en un solo resultado

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

quiero unir dos querys con las mismas columnas y mostrarlos en un solo resultado:

Tengo dos tablas una de proveedores mex y otro de proveedores USA.

esta es la estructura de las dos tablas

```html
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PROVEEDORES_USA](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [IDPROVEEDOR] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [RAZONSOCIAL] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [DENOCOMERCIAL] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [RFC] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [IMPUESTO] [int] NULL,
    [ESTATUS] [bit] NULL,
    [DIASCREDITO] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_PROVEEDORES_USA] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[PROVEEDORES]    Script Date: 10/05/2020 14:18:36 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PROVEEDORES](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [IDPROVEEDOR] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [RAZONSOCIAL] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [DENOCOMERNCIAL] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [RFC] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [IMPUESTO] [int] NULL,
    [ESTATUS] [bit] NULL,
    [DIASCREDITO] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_PROVEEDORES] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
```

y estos son mis dos querys que tengo actualmente.

Como pueden ver las columnas son las mismas, entonces quiero unir en un solo resultado ambos query.

```html
  /*proveedores mexicanos*/
SELECT A.FOLIO, B.IDPROVEEDOR,C.CurrentDep as DEP,A.CUENTA, D.CANTIDAD,A.COSTO,D.DESCRIPCION,D.ITEM,D.UNIMEDIDA,D.TIPOPROVEEDOR,A.PROVEEDOR
   from COTIZACION as A
   inner join [PROVEEDORES] as B on B.RAZONSOCIAL = A.PROVEEDOR
   inner join [CUENTAS]as C on c.Soft = A.DEPARTAMENTO
   inner join [REGCOTIZACIONES] D on D.ID = A.ID_RCOTI_CCOTI
   where A.APROBACIONESOK=4 AND A.ADMINPAQ IS NULL 
   ORDER BY A.FOLIO ASC
   go
   /*proveedores americanos*/
   SELECT A.FOLIO, B.IDPROVEEDOR,C.CurrentDep as DEP,A.CUENTA, D.CANTIDAD,A.COSTO,D.DESCRIPCION,D.ITEM,D.UNIMEDIDA,D.TIPOPROVEEDOR,A.PROVEEDOR
   from COTIZACION as A
   inner join [PROVEEDORES_USA] as B on B.RAZONSOCIAL = A.PROVEEDOR
   inner join [CUENTAS]as C on c.Soft = A.DEPARTAMENTO
   inner join [REGCOTIZACIONES] D on D.ID = A.ID_RCOTI_CCOTI
   where A.APROBACIONESOK=4 AND A.ADMINPAQ IS NULL 
   ORDER BY A.FOLIO ASC
```

El resultado que obtengo actualmente.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿No has probado hacer un `UNION`?

Comment: si eso era, solo que me estrese un poco y no pense en esa clausula